# I want cell A1 to say Open until I enter text or a date into cell A2 and change to closed

Tags: status

I want cell A1 to say Open until I enter text or a date into cell A2 and change to closed

The formula I am trying to use is `=IF(ISBLANK(I14),"open",C14)=If(...(I14),"Closed",C14)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using excel, you don't need two `if`s - only a single `if` that tests if `A2` is blank:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2), "Open", "Closed")
```